# Is Continual Flame affected by the object's size?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, vision-and-light

> A flame, equivalent in brightness to a torch, springs forth from an object that you touch.

If you cast [Continual Flame](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/continual-flame/) on a Fine-sized object, like a ring, would it cast a very small amount of light in line with a Fine-sized torch? Or would it cast light equivalent to a regular sized torch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

It always casts light equivalent to a [Torch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/hunting-camping-survival-geaR/#TOC-Torch), no matter the size of the object.

> A torch burns for 1 hour, shedding normal light in a 20-foot radius and increasing the light level by one step for an additional 20 feet beyond that area (darkness becomes dim light and dim light becomes normal light). A torch does not increase the light level in normal light or bright light. If a torch is used in combat, treat it as a one-handed improvised weapon that deals bludgeoning damage equal to that of a gauntlet of its size, plus 1 point of fire damage.

However, size may matter for partially obscured objects - if you obscure the object, it's light disappears as well. Hence, casting it on your armor may be more reliable than doing so on a ring or other trinket, since it's harder for any enemies to non-magically obscure it. An enemy might try to throw a piece of clothing over your hand if you have a ring emitting light - that's a lot harder if it's on your armor instead.

Comment: Darkness spells usually care about the spell level of magical light, not which mundane source its emulating. ("Magical light sources only increase the light level in an area if they are of a higher spell level than darkness", spell description of Darkness). Continual flame is level 2 for some classes and level 3 for others, so whether it is suppressed by the spell level 2 Darkness is dependant on who cast it.

Comment: Hm, I slightly misremembered wording. Yeah, it should fight for dominance with magical darkness. I thought for a bit that the Flame's light wouldn't count as magical, but that's wrong.

Comment: Of course, you might want something small so you can cover it yourself.

Comment: That's definitely a consideration, yeah.